# Radio button value is null

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the value of the radio button clicked but so far the value is null. The code below has a couple of things going on:
1) when the button is clicked it should move the radio buttons to the left. 
2) I need to the get value of which radio button is clicked

The first part works but I can't get the second part. This is my code:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form1").click(function(){
            $("#list_of_btns").animate({left: '-150px'});
        });
    });
</script> 

//this is the form for radio button...it must be centered to middle of the page

<div id="list_of_btns" style="padding-top: 80px; position:fixed;">
        <div class="row" style="position:fixed;">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4" style="position:fixed;">
                <div class="list-group" style="position:fixed;">

                    <form role="radio_button_form" style="position:fixed;">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label><input type="radio" value="male" name="method">male</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="radio">
                            <label><input type="radio" value="female" name="method">female</label>
                        </div>

                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

 //this is the enter button.
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 80px; position:relative;">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-16" style="position:relative;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="position:relative;">
       <asp:LinkButton class="btn btn-info" ID="getStarted_btn" runat="server" OnClick="btn_clicked" Text="Enter" />
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This is where I am trying to get value of the radio button, in my c# code:

```
public void btn_clicked (object sender, EventArgs args)

    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine ("sdsfdsfdfsdf");
        if (Request.Form["method"] != null)
        {
            string selectedGender = Request.Form["method"].ToString();
            Console.Out.WriteLine (selectedGender);
        }

    }
```

Does anybody have any idea on what I'm doing wrong or is there a better way in achieving this?

Comment: You can only submit one form at a time.

Comment: The radio buttons are not part of the form that was submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code and this is working.Plz check

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="position: relative;">
    <div id="list_of_btns" style="padding-top: 80px; position: fixed;">
        <div class="row" style="position: absolute;">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4" style="position: fixed;">
                <div class="list-group" style="position: fixed;">


                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" value="male" name="method">male</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" value="female" name="method">female</label>
                    </div>



                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 80px; position: relative;">
        <div style="position: relative;">

            <asp:LinkButton class="btn btn-info" ID="getStarted_btn" runat="server" OnClick="btn_clicked" Text="Enter" />

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Enclose the whole content inside single Form..